# How to get print from wifi printer with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wifi, printers, epson, network-printers

can any body tell me how to integrate wifi printer option in an iPhone app? I have to get print from small receipt printers and my printers are not AirPrint supported.
 My printer models are 
`EPSON TM T88, EPSON TM P60 and EPSON TM U220B` network printers

I want to acces the printer via IP address

Answer (score 1):

You must have an AirPrint supported printer.

References:
[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html)
[AirPrint 101](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356)

Comment: Infect i am working on an application and i have to give support for receipt printer, and these are the printers that will be used, and these are not AirPrint supported

Comment: I have to print on receipt printers. These printers are not AirPrint supported

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you must have an AirPrint supported printer.  However there are workarounds:

The procedure [here](http://jaxov.com/2010/11/how-to-enable-airprint-service-on-windows/) will allow you to print to any printer connected to windows.

[Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) will allow it on Macs.

I'm sure there are other methods/applications that allow it as well, just search them on Google or the App Store.

Comment: Infect i am working on an application and i have to give support for receipt printer, and these are the printers that will be used, and these are not AirPrint supported

Answer (score 1):

Printing over wifi with the iphone is somewhat of an iffy issue, only some printers are supported and for most of them a mac machine is obligatory.

However if you have jailbroken your phone you can search in cydia for an app that's called truprint. This one allows you to print with every printer that has wifi capability. The app is not free but there is a light version that i think will cover your needs.

Comment: Infect i am working on an application and i have to give support for receipt printer, and these are the printers that will be used, and these are not AirPrint supported

Comment: I find a solution, I'll have to make its drivers by my self, i got a document of its commands

Answer (score 1):

For Epson receipt printers there is the ePOS-SDK for iOS. Using this you can print via WiFi and Bluetooth. The SDK is provided here:
http://download.epson-biz.com/

Answer (score 0):

try the print n share or printcentral apps